# Is there an NGINX equivalent of Apache's Directory Interpolation

Tags: apache, nginx, mod-vhost-alias

With Apache's mod_vhost_alias you can use Directory Interpolation to serve sites based on directory structure.  See here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#interpol

Is this possible with NGINX? if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest one would be:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/$host;
}
```

For `http://www.example.com/directory/file.html` this will serve file `/var/www/www.example.com/directory/file.html`.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found out through randomly searching for something else that the exact same functionality as Apache's Directory Interpolation (and more) can be achieved using regex, for example...

```
server_name "~^(?<machine>.*?)\.(?<domain>.*?)\.(?<group>.*?)\.dev$";
root "/some/place/projects/$group/$domain/$machine";
```

For anyone coming here wanting to auto manage their local webserver setup, I found these useful to take care of the DNS side of things

https://echo.co/blog/never-touch-your-local-etchosts-file-os-x-again (mac)
http://mayakron.altervista.org/wikibase/show.php?id=AcrylicHome (win)